# Is it preferrable to use autowired constructor in Spring config classes instead of member autowiring?

Tags: java, spring

In Spring for common bean classes it is preferrable to use the constructor for autowiring, as far as I know. But is this also the case for configuration classes? Does it have any disadvantages in the case of config classes?

For example:

```java
@Configuration
public class ConfigA {
...
}

@Configuration
public class ConfigB {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigA configA;
...
}

// versus 
@Configuration
public class ConfigB {

    private final ConfigA configA;

    public ConfigB(ConfigA configA) {
        this.configA = configA;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: "*Is it even possible?*" This should be very easy to test for yourself, no? You have already written the code here. What's stopping you from running it?

Comment: "*Is it preferable?*" The Spring team advocate for constructor injection in the documentation. Constructor injection guarantees `configA` will be non-null. Field injection does not.

Comment: All the examples in the Spring documentation use field injection. Therefore I think the question is appropriate...

Comment: Field injection is shorter, so results in more concise examples, so that's probably why they use it in the docs. Like I said, they specifically advocate for constructor injection: ["The Spring team generally advocates constructor injection"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/dependencies/factory-collaborators.html#beans-constructor-vs-setter-injection). I never said your question wasn't appropriate. I asked why you didn't try it yourself.

Comment: I have reworded my doubts in case that lead to the downvoting. That it compiles and runs in a simple example I know.

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted FYI.  There is nothing special about `@Configuration` here. Constructor injection has the same benefits over field injection regardless of what the class is annotated with.